# Python/HTML Integration

Tags: python, html

Im kind of a noob in coding, as i just got into it very recently. I was wondering if there was any way to link a python script directly into an HTML document. I remember seeing an earlier thread on Stack Overflow saying all you had to do was:

```
<script type='text/python'>#Python code here</script>
```

Is this true, or is it much more complicated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, python cannot be natively run in a browser. It needs to be interpreted first, producing HTML to be displayed.

Check the official documentation, CGI is probably your best bet. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html